# illegal_argument_exception for datetime

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use a default date format in Elasticsearch.

```
"mydate": {
   "type":"date"
}
```

However, when I try to put some data, it fails:

```
POST test-index/entry/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"mydate":"2016-05-15 18:00:15"}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"mydate":"2016-05-16 19:05:00"}
```

Error message:

```
caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": """Invalid format: "2016-05-15 18:00:15" is malformed at "18:00:15""""
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format your dates according to the ISO 8601 format, i.e. `2016-05-15T18:00:15`, i.e. you're missing the `T`

```
POST test-index/entry/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"mydate":"2016-05-15T18:00:15"}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"mydate":"2016-05-16T19:05:00"}
```